# copying the db4o file doesn't copy the data in it

Tags: asp.net, db4o

I have a db4o file with data in it, when i try to copy the file to another project, the data gets empty ? what is the reason behind it ? Can some one explain it to me ?

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

db4o keep all the data inside one single file.

Probably what is happening is that in the new project you have different assembly/namespace names.

Since db4o relies on these names it fails to find the objects.

What happens if you query for all objects? (I guess you will get back instance of *GenericObject*.

To fix this you should either have a common assembly with your object model or use db4o [aliases](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/net35/reference/Content/configuration/common/alias.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=alias%7CAlias).